# dhcpd server-identifier has same fixed-address

Tags: dhcp

Why my dhcp server ip has leased to dhcp client?

This is my dhcpd.conf

```
subnet 192.168.254.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 192.168.254.1 192.168.254.254;
}
host 402c2627-a493-3b1e-bcd4-db72414e891cbond0-10-1 {
    hardware ethernet 00:0C:29:A6:A0:CB;
    fixed-address 192.168.254.1;
}
host 402c2627-a493-3b1e-bcd4-db72414e891cbond0-10-2 {
    hardware ethernet 00:0C:29:A6:A0:C1;
    fixed-address 192.168.254.1;
}
```

This is interface bond0.10 configure

```
DEVICE="bond0.10"
VLAN="yes"
ONBOOT="yes"
BOOTPROTO="static"
IPADDR="192.168.254.1"
NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
```

This is my dhcpd.lease file

```
lease 192.168.254.1 {
  starts 3 2014/09/17 09:01:54;
  ends 3 2014/09/17 21:01:54;
  cltt 3 2014/09/17 09:01:54;
  binding state active;
  next binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 00:0c:29:5d:d8:a2;
}
```

This is my dhclient-bond0.10.lease file

```
lease {
  interface "bond0.10";
  fixed-address 192.168.254.1;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option dhcp-lease-time 43200;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.254.1;
  renew 3 2014/09/17 13:59:18;
  rebind 3 2014/09/17 19:31:53;
  expire 3 2014/09/17 21:01:53;
}
```

And there is my dhcpd&dhclient version

```
[root@localhost lib]# dhcpd --version
isc-dhcpd-4.1.1-P1
[root@localhost lib]# dhclient --version
isc-dhclient-4.1.1-P1
```

And my os version is

```
[root@localhost lib]# dhclient --version
isc-dhclient-4.1.1-P1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you change this line:

```
range 192.168.254.1 192.168.254.254;
```

to:

```
range 192.168.254.2 192.168.254.254;
```